# Issue with RAReorderableLayout didmovetoindexpath class

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift3

I am trying to implement the RAReorderableLayout from GitHub. I've got this code that I believe should work.

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, atIndexPath: IndexPath, didMoveToIndexPath toIndexPath: IndexPath) {

    var pickeddate: String
    var pickedimage: String
    var pickedsince: String

    pickeddate = Globals.datesArray.remove(at: (atIndexPath as NSIndexPath).item)
    pickedimage = Globals.imagesArray.remove(at: (atIndexPath as NSIndexPath).item)
    pickedsince = Globals.sinceLabelArray.remove(at: (atIndexPath as NSIndexPath).item)


    Globals.datesArray.insert(pickeddate, at: (toIndexPath as NSIndexPath).item)
    Globals.imagesArray.insert(pickedimage, at: (toIndexPath as NSIndexPath).item)
    Globals.sinceLabelArray.insert(pickedsince, at: (toIndexPath as NSIndexPath).item)

    UserDefaults.standard.set(Globals.datesArray, forKey: "saveddates")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(Globals.sinceLabelArray, forKey: "savedsincelabels")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(Globals.imagesArray, forKey: "themearray")


}
```

But when I rearrange a cell, there is a problem with the data transfer. The cell that is taking the space of the previous cell becomes that cell.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you post this issue to the issue tag of the framework on Github better.
https://github.com/ra1028/RAReorderableLayout/issues

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, do you see any issues with the code I'm using?

Comment: Sorry I have not used this framework.